# MVC linq query export to Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, linq, export

I have a controller, where I use a linq query and whose input is saved into a list and is shown in the view, now I want to have the option to also export the input of the query into excel.
I have so far only seen tutorials where you can export the content of a table into excel, but my query isn't saved in a table and so I want to export the query content.
this is how my controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult ControllingTagestouren(string sortorder, string tName, string sName)
    {
var query1 = from q in query
                     where q.Tagestourname == tName || tName == null || tName == ""
                     where q.Standardtourname == sName || sName == null || sName == ""
                     select q;

        List<Tagestourauswertung> TagesAuswertung = new List<Tagestourauswertung>();
        TagesAuswertung.AddRange(query1);
        return View(TagesAuswertung);
```

This is what I found so far but it doesn't work...
Its in the same controller class

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
    {
        ControllingController cc = new ControllingController();
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = cc.ControllingTagestouren(null, null, null);
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return RedirectToAction("ControllingTagestouren");
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP - please remove the tag.

Comment: sry, I didnt want to tag asp-classic :( probably done automatically

Comment: Probably because you used the [tag:asp] tag - this aliases to [tag:asp-classic]. [An on going battle](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269402/can-we-clarify-the-asp-classic-and-asp-net-tags-for-the-uneducated)!

Comment: this is more complicated and simply adding header will not help. Please look at this article http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/06/16/asp-net-mvc-tip-2-create-a-custom-action-result-that-returns-microsoft-excel-documents Here you will find code and great details